# how to display products side by side

Tags: html, css

This is my product template file.

```
<br>
<div>
    <div ng-if="SearchText.length<3" ng-repeat="product in pc.ProductService.Products  | filter:FilterExpr:true |orderBy:['SubCategoryName','BrandName'] | groupBy:['BrandName']" >
        <h2 ng-show="product.group_by_CHANGED">{{product.BrandName}} </h2>
        <div class='box'>
            <ng-include src="'commonTemplate.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
    </div>  



    <!-- template (common piece of code) -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="commonTemplate.html">
        <div class="BrandName"> <b>{{product.BrandName}}</b> </div>
        <div class="ProductName"> {{product.ProductName}} </div>
        <br>
        <div> <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img> </div>
        <div class="ProductVariants"> 
            <select class="form-control btn btn-default btn-xs text-center" ng-init="SelectedVariant = product.Variants[0]" ng-model="SelectedVariant" ng-options="variant.VariantName for variant in product.Variants" ng-change="ChangeVariant(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)"></select>
        </div>

        <div class="Price"> 
            <strike> {{SelectedVariant.MRP}} </strike> &nbsp; {{SelectedVariant.SellPrice}} 
        </div>      

        <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart==0">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="pc.AddToCart(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">Add to Cart &nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart>0">

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.PlusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info disabled">{{SelectedVariant.InCart}} in cart</button>


            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
            </a>
        </div>

    </script>

</div>
```

Box class is defined like this in CSS:

```
.box {
margin : 5px;
display : inline-block;
width: 170px;
height: 275px;
background-color: #F5FBEF;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

When display my product list look like this:

[image]

I want to show products side by side.

Can some one help me how to do that?

EDIT:

After changes suggested by Rachel Gallen, it turn out like this:

[image]

I want to display brand name in new line when new brand encounters. rest all looks good.

Comment: looking at the .box class it should be aligned side by side, maybe the parent doesnt have enough width so it push down the .box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put in .ng-repeat:display:inline plus a wrapper

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline!important;
  height: 275px;
  max-width: 540px;
}
.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 275px!important;
  background-color: #F5FBEF;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
.ng-repeat {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div ng-if="SearchText.length<3" ng-repeat="product in pc.ProductService.Products  | filter:FilterExpr:true |orderBy:['SubCategoryName','BrandName'] | groupBy:['BrandName']">
      <h2 ng-show="product.group_by_CHANGED">{{product.BrandName}} </h2>
      <div id=wrapper>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class="BrandName"> <b>{{product.BrandName}}</b> 
          </div>
          <div class="ProductName">{{product.ProductName}}</div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img>
          </div>
          <div class="ProductVariants">
            <select class="form-control btn btn-default btn-xs text-center" ng-init="SelectedVariant = product.Variants[0]" ng-model="SelectedVariant" ng-options="variant.VariantName for variant in product.Variants" ng-change="ChangeVariant(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)"></select>
          </div>

          <div class="Price">
            <strike> {{SelectedVariant.MRP}} </strike> &nbsp; {{SelectedVariant.SellPrice}}
          </div>

          <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart==0">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="pc.AddToCart(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">Add to Cart &nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart>0">

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.PlusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info disabled">{{SelectedVariant.InCart}} in cart</button>


            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='box'>
          <div class="BrandName"> <b>{{product.BrandName}}</b> 
          </div>
          <div class="ProductName">{{product.ProductName}}</div>
          <br>
          <div>
            <img src="http://localhost/{{ product.ProductImagePath }}" alt="" border=3 height=75 width=75></img>
          </div>
          <div class="ProductVariants">
            <select class="form-control btn btn-default btn-xs text-center" ng-init="SelectedVariant = product.Variants[0]" ng-model="SelectedVariant" ng-options="variant.VariantName for variant in product.Variants" ng-change="ChangeVariant(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)"></select>
          </div>

          <div class="Price">
            <strike> {{SelectedVariant.MRP}} </strike> &nbsp; {{SelectedVariant.SellPrice}}
          </div>

          <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart==0">
            <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="pc.AddToCart(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">Add to Cart &nbsp;
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="AddToCart" ng-if="SelectedVariant.InCart>0">

            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.PlusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> 
            </a>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info disabled">{{SelectedVariant.InCart}} in cart</button>


            <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="pc.MinusItem(product.ProductID, SelectedVariant.VariantID)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> 
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>






    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated my question after integrating your suggestions. I want to display brand name in new line.

Comment: with your edits also look is same. Anyways i am accepting your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Did you set your wrapper to 540 wide and ng I repeat to display inline block?

Comment: yes. i made both the changes. Also i created a new question. This is SO link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693837/how-to-display-new-brand-in-new-line

Answer (score 0):

Add property `float:left` to `box` class. If that doesn't work, please provide a demo.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9jbhmd4/

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float` in your css:

```
.box {
margin : 5px;
display : inline-block;
width: 170px;
height: 275px;
background-color: #F5FBEF;
text-align:center;
vertical-align: top; 
float: left;
}
```

And to keep the height of the container, move `<div class="box">...</div>` inside container like `<div class="box-container">.....</div>`

Then, add css:

```
.box-container:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```